# SQL statement to retrieve data from single table by comparing with multiple table entries

Tags: sql

I have a table `category`, `profile` and `employee_belongs_to`, where `employee_belongs_to` stores profile_id and category_id. The `profile` table stores all the employees details. `category` table stores different category like English, math,physics  ...

I want to select only name from `profile` table to which profile_id corresponds to particular category_id in `employee_belongs_to` table.

How can i write the SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following SQL statement worked for me:

```
SELECT profile.* FROM profile JOIN employee_belongs_to JOIN category ON employee_belongs_to.Profile_id=profile.Profile_id AND employee_belongs_to.Category_id=category.Category_id WHERE category.Category_id=?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the tables and write query like shown below

```
SELECT * 
FROM profile INNER JOIN employee_belongs_to ON employee_belongs_to.profileID = profile.ProfileID
             INNER JOIN category ON category.categoryID = employee_belongs_to.categoryID
WHERE category.categoryID = @CategoryID
```

Comment: #1052 - Column 'Category_id' in where clause is ambiguous .I got error like this

Comment: @Bhagawat Edited